# Query a local ttl file using SPARQL on Virtuoso Conductor?

Tags: sparql, virtuoso

I am trying to learn SPARQL and I am trying to query a local **ttl file** which is my downloads

The path is : `C:/Users/abc/Downloads/human-instructions-english-wikihow/en_0_rdf_result.ttl`

```
SELECT ?s ?p ?o
FROM <C:/Users/abc/Downloads/human-instructions-english-wikihow/en_0_rdf_result.ttl>
WHERE {?s ?p ?o}
LIMIT 1000
```

So I am trying to execute a very simple query like this but it does not return any output.

I understand we have to put a SPARQL endpoint or something with '`http`' in FROM but this file is on my Downloads and I cant seem to figure out what would be the endpoint.

Please, help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: 4 years ago this wasn't possible unless you use import the file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23607443/openlink-virtuoso-query-local-remote-rdf-file - not sure if this works now. By the way, your second query doesn't make any sense, it's not even valid SPARQL syntax

Comment: Yes, I understand, the prefix declaration probably is incorrect, I was just trying it out as I saw some similar query. Sorry about that and also, thanks for your help.

Comment: not only the prefix declaration, but also that the query body is made of triple patterns, but yours is something .. different. Never seen this syntax before. Where did you see such a query?

Comment: Regarding your initial query, you could also ask in the Openlink forum if there is some way to solve what you're trying to achieve. Though I think TallTed and others will answer here soon.

Comment: @AKSW I was looking at some youtube videos and the person wrote something similar to like this not exactly like this though.His query worked so I am pretty sure he was doing something correct. However the bottom query I just tried to write it on my own and hence such a blunder, I guess. I should remove that to avoid confusion I think.

Answer (score 1):

(If you haven't already, you need to install the Virtuoso Sponger Middleware module, `cartridges_dav.vad`, for your version of Virtuoso [Enterprise/Commercial Edition](http://download3.openlinksw.com/index.html?prefix=uda/vad-packages/) or [Open Source Edition](http://download3.openlinksw.com/index.html?prefix=uda/vad-vos-packages/).)

First, you need to add this line to the top of your SPARQL query --

```
define get:soft "replace"
```

That "`define` pragma" is a SPARQL extension, which tells Virtuoso to resolve remote URLs it encounters in the rest of the query.

Then, you need to use a full URI for the target file. This may be a `file:` scheme URI, *IFF* --

- the URI is properly constructed
- the target file is accessible through the filesystem where Virtuoso is running
- the directory holding the target file is included in the `DirsAllowed` parameter in the `virtuoso.ini` file

Also see [How to import JSON-LD into Virtuoso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32298456/how-to-import-json-ld-into-virtuoso/32317652#32317652).